# Assigning User to a role error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a register process where persons provide email/ password..
also they will provide there membership (Or Role)

my AccountController Register Method looks like..

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.SelectedMembershipType);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                    var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
                    ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;
                    return View("DisplayEmail");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
```

but i get an error stating ..
[image]

which basically states UserId not found. Has anyone had this before and could you recommend a solution to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: where you have used `UserId` ?

Comment: Hi, User.Id is part of IdentityUser.cs which is a primary key. I have ran thru debug and it shows an id on the trace but for some reason when i step over the error above happens

Comment: fixed this by moving the highlighted error (in red) to past if(result.Succeeded){

Comment: this got tagged as a duplicate .. and have given a link to what they suspect is the answer (up top) .. but is not! Mine is above

Comment: When same question with the same problem is already asked by you or some other person then it would be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: different resolution though